# Java8 lambda: sort a stream in reverse order?

Tags: lambda, collections, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I have this list that I want to order in reserve order, but I didn't find any `.reversed()` function in autocomplete assist

```
 myMenus(user)
                .stream()
                .filter(mps ->  mps.get1PercentageChange() > 0 &&
                                mps.get2PercentageChange() > 0 &&
                                mps.get3PercentageChange() > 0 &
                                mps.get4PercentageChange() > 0)
                .sorted(comparing(mps -> mps.getDailyPercentageChange()))
                .collect(toList());
```

I have also tried:

```
myMenus(user)
        .stream()
        .filter(mps ->  mps.get1PercentageChange() > 0 &&
                        mps.get2PercentageChange() > 0 &&
                        mps.get3PercentageChange() > 0 &
                        mps.get4PercentageChange() > 0)
        .sorted(comparing(mps -> mps.getDailyPercentageChange()).reversed())
        .collect(toList());
```

but then I have the compilation error:

```
Cannot infer type argument(s) for <T, U> comparing(Function<? super T,? 
     extends U>)
```

Comment: How about just using `comparing(mps -> -mps.getDailyPercentageChange())`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a type inference issue. You'll need to help the compiler out.

few things you could try:

```
.sorted(comparing(T::getDailyPercentageChange).reversed())
```

or

```
.sorted(comparing((T mps) -> mps.getDailyPercentageChange()).reversed())
```

Where `T` is the type of elements being compared.

Answer (score 5):

`Comparator`s have a `reversed` method to get the reverse ordering, so :

```
.sorted(comparing(mps -> mps.getDailyPercentageChange()).reversed())
```

should work.

Comment: How about using a method reference instead: `.sorted(comparing(Mps::getDailyPercentageChange).reversed())` (where `Mps` is the type of `mps`)? That would be a bit more readable.

Comment: Depending on the class name length, a lambda can sometimes be conciser. I also presume that `Mps` is not the actual class name but an acronym.